# my JQuery .click() function wont work with the android chrome browser

Tags: android, html, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I have buttons that reveal nav links on click that dont work on my mobile chrome browser (I use a google pixel 2) I also have firefox mobile and it works fine there. it also works fine on the simulated phone sizes on my computer browsers.

here's my HTML

```
<div class="nav">
           
     <button class="nav_btn nav1_trig"><p>WORK</p></button>
            
            <div class="navItem nav1_pop external_links"> 
                <a class="proj_1_trig" title="" href="#"> link </a>
                <a class="proj_2_trig" title="" href="#"> link</a>
            </div>

</div>
```

the `<button class="nav_btn nav1_trig"><p>WORK</p></button>` is supposed to reveal the links below when clicked.

here's my Jquery

```
$(".nav1_trig").click(function(){
    $(".nav1_pop").toggle(300);});
```

I've tried switching to `.on('click', function(){` and `.on('click touchstart', function(){`
as well along with a bunch of other random fixes like giving the button the "button" type, turning it into a regular  link, all with no results.

I also have a div with just a link in it that executes essentially the same code when clicked or tapped that works just FINE on my mobile chrome browser. What am I doing wrong here?

here's that div with the link that works fine on mobile chrome:

```
<div class="myInfo" id="about">
           <a class="about_trig"  title="" ><span>about me</span></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: maybe your jquery tries to find an element that only has a class ```nav1_trig``` and it is not able to detect it because the one you want to click has other classes too. the code that was working had a single class and that could be why it is working.